# static final Date field in a java class

Tags: java, java.util.date

We've a public static util method which can parse a string and return a Date object, but it also throws ParseException in case the string parsed cannot be converted to a Date object.

Now, in another class I would like to have a static final Date initialized to a value using the util method described above. But given that the util method throws ParseException, this is not allowed.

This is what I want to do, which is not allowed

```
public static final MY_DATE = Util.getDateFromString('20000101');
```

What is the recommended way to keep this Date field 'final'?

Comment: mutable in a public static field is high undesirable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you *could* use a static initializer block:

```
public static final Date MY_DATE;

static {
    try {
       MY_DATE = Util.getDateFromString("20000101");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
       // Whatever you want to do here. You might want to throw
       // an unchecked exception, or you might want to use some fallback value.
       // If you want to use a fallback value, you'd need to use a local
       // variable for the result of parsing, to make sure you only have a
       // single assignment to the final variable.
    }
}
```

However, I would advise against this. `Date` is a mutable type - exposing it via a public static final variable is a bad idea.

As of Java 8, the `java.time` package is the most appropriate to use for almost all date/time work, where you'd write:

```
public static final LocalDate START_OF_JANUARY_2000 = LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1);
```

Prior to Java 8, I'd recommend that you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which has many *immutable* date/time types - and is a thoroughly better library for working with dates and times. It looks like you'd want:

```
public static final LocalDate START_OF_JANUARY_2000 = new LocalDate(2000, 1, 1);
```

Note that even if you *do* decide to go with `java.util.Date`, it doesn't make much sense to parse the string in my view - you know the values numerically, so why not just supply them that way? If you haven't got a suitable method to construct a `Date` from a year / month / day (presumably applying an appropriate time zone) then you could easily write one.

Comment: This doesn't compile with 'final' keyword. It compiles only if we remove 'final' and that is what we have in our code currently. But your second suggestion of creating a date from year/month/day seems reasonable. Thanks.

Comment: @Ramesh: It should compile using `final`, if you make your `catch` block throw a `RuntimeException` to indicate the unexpected failure. But it would still be better not to have a potentially-exception-throwing initializer to start with...

Comment: The util method is coming from a library where we do not have the liberty to change the signature. I'll go with your last suggestion of initializing the date directly using the constructor of GregorianCalendar, something like public static final Date = new GregorianCalendar(2000, 0, 1).getTime();

Comment: @Ramesh: That will use the default system time zone - is that really what you want? (It also leaves you with a mutable `Date` still. I would really, really encourage you to go with Joda Time.)

Comment: @Ramesh, `Date` is _mutable_, `final` just prevent it from being reassigned but the value could still be changed.

Comment: @Rosdi, yep, understand the risks. Just wanted a sense of pseudo security (or semi-security) feeling as we don't want to get into introducing a new Date library for this :)

Comment: @DanielWiddis: Please don't roll back my rollback. I'm editing, and will have *something* in there, but you're changing the post's intent, which is against the spirit of editing.

Comment: Sorry about that. Your code as written is causing confusion, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63115630/initialize-static-final-date-using-custom-string. I'll leave it to you to finish.

Comment: @DanielWiddis: In that situation it would have been better to add a comment drawing my attention to it, instead of guessing at the intention.

Comment: Understood, and again, my apologies.

Comment: If I may humbly suggest another edit. The "fallback value" in the catch clause doesn't work because of the `final` keyword, which was the point of confusion in the other post. So an exception must be thrown, or a temporary variable used and eventually assigned (once) to MY_DATE.

Comment: @DanielWiddis: Done.

Answer (score 2):

OMG! I finally get to out-do Jon Skeet with a better, more elite, more elegant answer!

One neat way is to use an anonymous class, with an instance block, like this:

```
public static final Date MY_DATE = new Date() {{
    try {
        setTime(Util.getDateFromString("20000101").getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}};
```

This works because (remarkably) `java.util.Date` is not immutable!

To make the Date immutable, and therefore more acceptable design-wise, override the setter methods too:

```
public static final Date MY_DATE = new Date() {{
        try {
            super.setTime(Util.getDateFromString("20000101").getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    // Formatted for brevity :)
    @Override public void setYear(int year) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
    @Override public void setMonth(int month) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
    @Override public void setDate(int date) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
    @Override public void setHours(int hours) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
    @Override public void setMinutes(int minutes) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
    @Override public void setSeconds(int seconds) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
    @Override public void setTime(long time) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
};
```

Comment: My answer recommends the use of Joda Time instead, which has immutable types and is a nicer library to start with :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh come on... you gotta love the 1337 work-around :) Actually, a combo of joda and the static instance block idea is probably the go. btw, I take my hat off to you - just how many badges can one man get!? You're a badge and rep *factory*!

Comment: Thanks Bohemian. +1 for the DBI (Double brace initialization) approach. But I'll go with the last suggestion mentioned by Jon for now where I can say MY_DATE = new GregorianCalendar(2000,0,1).getTime();

Answer (score 1):

Another way, if you're sure you won't *actually* get the declared exception, is to create another method, either locally or in Util, that wraps the ParseException in an unchecked exception, like this:

```
public static final Date MY_DATE = getDateFromStringWithoutExploding("20000101");

private static Date getDateFromStringWithoutExploding(String dateString) {
    try {
        return Util.getDateFromStringWithoutExploding(dateString);
    catch(ParseException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}
```

This is reasonable, and actually reflects what's going on anyway - you *know* the date string you are passing in is OK, so the try-catch is perfunctory.

Answer (score 0):

It's been stated in a comment, but to make it more explicit:

```
public static final MY_DATE = new GregorianCalendar(2000, 1, 1).getTime();
```

Do this only if you can live with a mutable date assigned to a public static final.