# Initialize static final Date using custom String

Tags: java, java-8, static, final

I am working with Java and come through one random problem.
Here I had shared sample code of my problem.

I want to initialize some of static final date field with my custom string format.

```
public class Sample {
    protected static final Date MAX_DATE ;
    static {
        try {
            MAX_DATE = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2099-12-31");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

While directly putting below line, it's asking for try and catch.

`protected static final Date MAX_DATE= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2099-12-31");`

When I had added try and catch as mentioned in above code, it's throwing an error

> Variable 'MAX_DATE' might not have been initialized

While initialize with below code, it started throwing an error of `Cannot assign a value to final variable 'MAX_DATE'` on line number 5.

`protected static final Date MAX_DATE=null;`

Can somebody help me in this issue?

Comment: Ask yourself a question - what value would `MAX_DATE` have if an exception is thrown? You need to assing some value to it inside of `catch` block as well.

Comment: You just need to have `MAX_DATE = null;` in your `catch` block (as null is the value you want to set as default). But you should probably be using `java.time.LocalDate` instead of `Date` (the latter is mutable and obsolete)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [static final Date field in a java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471063/static-final-date-field-in-a-java-class)

Comment: `catch(ParseException e) { throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need a plain date, you should use `LocalDate` instead of `Date`:

```
protected static final LocalDate MAX_DATE = LocalDate.of(2099, 12, 31);
```

If (for whatever reason) the date has to be taken from a String, you can also use it as follows:

```
protected static final LocalDate MAX_DATE = LocalDate.parse("2099-12-31");
```

In case it is really a hard requirement to

- have the date parsed from String of arbitrary pattern and
- use good ol' `java.util.Date`

something like that should do the trick:

```
protected static final Date MAX_DATE = Date.from(LocalDate.parse("2088||12||31", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy||MM||dd")).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Comment: It is a constant. What is the benefit of parsing it from String instead of initializing it correctly?

Comment: @Seb , In future it may come like `"31||12||99"`, in that case i need to parse through `SimpleDateFormat`. Also i need to implement through `Date` only.

Comment: Conversion from LocalDate to Date can be easily achieved using Date#from, leading to readable code like the following:
Date.from(LocalDate.parse("2099-12-31").atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

Comment: And what about string with this format `"31||12||99"` ??

Comment: Add formatter to the expression: Date.from(LocalDate.parse("2088||12||31", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy||MM||dd")).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

Comment: But I personally would think about the flexibility that is really needed here, since this looks overly complicated to me. In the end this code simply stands for a fixed date, which is why I initially suggested skipping the whole "parsing from string"-stuff.

Comment: @Seb, Actually content of this java file is created dynamically with some external system. And that system may follow any pattern of `DateFormatter`, so i can't directly make that change you had suggested. I can go with `Date.from(LocalDate.parse("2088||12||31", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy||MM||dd")).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()); `

Comment: Working with legacy-code is great sometimes, isn't it? ;) I updated my answer again, hoping that it at least gave you some new insights. At least you do not have to deal with checked exceptions in this case.

Comment: What is the relevance of this unusual `||` separator? In what regard does `||` work better than the `-` the OP originally used?

Comment: For yyyy-mm-dd you can simply use LocalDate.parse("2099-12-31"). No need for formatter here.
I chose yyyy||MM||dd, because OP used it as example in the comments.

Comment: @Seb , It's  working by simply putting `catch(ParseException e) { throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e); }`

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Change `protected static final Date MAX_DATE;` to `protected static final Date MAX_DATE = null;` and keep try-catch block
2. To get rid of try-catch block - add `throws ParseException` between `Sample` and `{`